# How is the Vulgate rendering of Romans 5:12 explained (Roman Catholic perspective)?

Tags: catholicism, bible-translation, original-sin, greek, latin-vulgate

The Greek text (Textus Receptus) of Romans 5:12 reads:

> δια τουτο ωσπερ δι ενος ανθρωπου η αμαρτια εις τον κοσμον εισηλθεν και
>   δια της αμαρτιας ο θανατος και ουτως εις παντας ανθρωπους ο θανατος
>   διηλθεν εφ ω παντες ημαρτον

Which one fairly literal translation ([*The Orthodox New Testament Praxapostolos*](http://amzn.to/2mjkwyz)) renders:

> *Therefore, even as through one man sin entered into the world, and death through sin, and thus death passed to all men, on account of
>   which all have sinned*

But the Vulgate translates the final phrase ("on account of which all have sinned" - εφ ω παντες ημαρτον) as *in quo omnes peccaverunt*.  The Douay-Rheims translation of the Vulgate reads therefore:

> *Wherefore as by one man sin entered into this world and by sin death: and so death passed upon all men, **in whom all have sinned**.*

The implication is that somehow all have sinned in Adam - i.e. they inherit the guilt of Adam's sin.  Unless I am misunderstanding the apparatus, there is no variant in the Greek text that supports this wording.  John Chrysostom - a 4th century Greek Doctor of the Roman Catholic Church - does not seem to interpret the verse this way in his [homily on the passage](http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/210210.htm).

My understanding is that the verse appeared this way in Latin in Augustine's *De Peccato Originale*, which also introduced the term "original sin" in the west, though perhaps that was not the first occurrence.

It seems that the Augustinian-Vulgate understanding of this verse has seeped into other English translations to various degrees.  While the King James is close to the literal translation above (*And so death passed upon all men, for that all have sinned*), other translations follow more closely the Latin meaning.  The ESV and RSV state, for example, *... and so death spread to all men because all sinned* (i.e. cause and effect are transposed).

Is there some reasoned explanation for the apparent departure of the Vulgate from the Greek text of Romans 5:12?

(Perhaps this should be posted in BH instead, but since the passage of interest touches on theological differences between Christians I thought to post it here.)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, *in quo* is a very literal translation of the Greek *ἐφ' ᾧ*, which is preposition *ἐπῐ́* ruling the dative article *ᾧ*. In Latin, *ἐπῐ́* translates to *in*. As Quintillian said, *"Noster sermo articulos non desiderat"*, *our language does not use articles*, so the article has to become something else. Here it becomes a relative pronoun, and goes to ablative to satisfy Latin syntax.

So much for linguistics; what does *ἐπῐ́ + dative* mean?  According to Wiktionary, which sources Liddell & Scott:

> (with dative)
>
> - on, upon
>
>   > καθέζεται ἐπὶ θρόνῳ.‎ //
>   >     kathézetai epì thrónōi. //
>   >     He sits down on the throne.
> - in
> - at, near
> - over
> - in honor of
> - against
> - in addition to, over, besides
> - (with duplication of head noun) after
>
>   > ὄγχνη ἐπ’ ὄγχνῃ γηράσκει‎ //
>   >     ónkhnē ep’ ónkhnēi gēráskei //
>   >     One pear after another ripens.
> - in the power of
> - according to
> - (of conditions or circumstances) in, with
> - (of time, never in proper Attic) at, on
> - (of time) after
> - (expressing a cause) on account of, for
> - (expressing a purpose) for
> - (of a condition) on
> - for (i.e. in exchange for)
> - (of a name) for
> - in charge of

In all, 19 different senses. So which one of the 19 is right?  That depends on context, and different translators might validly pick different options here. The *Praxapostolos* you quoted picks sense 14, "(expressing a cause) on account of, for". The Latin *in* is closer to senses 1, 2 and 3.

Of course, the sentence must make sense theologically, so not all senses may be used, but if one does not start with a position where the sin of Adam *cannot* be the same original sin all inherit, then one *can* definitely come to this reading.

Comment: "ᾧ" is indeed a relative pronoun in Greek: the article would be "τῷ"

Comment: Any indication of how Greek commentators interpreted the phrase?  It seems that Chrysostom reads the verse in "sense 14" as well.  I didn't look too deeply into the writings of others, though.